# ASP.Net file upload with an empty posted files collection

Tags: asp.net, jquery, file-upload, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-forms-plugin

I have an ASP.NET file upload control which sits as part of a form. The file upload control is on the content page while the form definition is on a master page across the site. I've added multipart/form-enc to the form on the master page.

I'm using jQuery to submit the form as I show a dialog box from jQuery UI.

When I post, no file is returned to the server. The file upload control has no file and HttpFileCollection is empty. How can I find the posted file?

Comment: Are all other controls you place in the dialog empty on postback as well?

Comment: Have you run fiddler to verify the files being posted by the browser. Here is a link to fiddler

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 5):

Most dialogs take your content, wrap it, and place the result just before `</body>` in the page...this is a problem in ASP.Net because that's outside the `<form></form>`, it needs to be inside to be included in the POSTed data.

When you create the dialog, make it append inside the `<form>` when it finishes instead of the `<body>`, for example this is what you'd do with the [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/):

```
$("#myDiv").dialog({ ...options... }).parent().appendTo("form:first");
```

Now that it's been moved inside the `<form>`, it should post correctly.

Comment: I think it's something along these lines as all the form values are blank. I've added the append code but still the same problem.

Comment: Is there only one <form> tag on your page? If so, that .appendTo() code should work-- otherwise you need to specify the actual form ID, like .appendTo('#formidhere');

Comment: @Nicholas - The OP is using webforms...only one `<form>` tag, one of the defining characteristics :)

Comment: @Nicholas - Not with ASP.Net **WebForms** (he's using the File Upload Control), not unless you're really hacking around.

Comment: Nick, jQuery doesn't care if it's a server-side <form> tag or just a regular form tag. You can have multiple form tags on your page, as long as only one is runat="server". I've done it with PayPal integration, among other things.

Comment: @Nicholas - Read the question "the form on the master page", you can't have nested forms (it's invalid), he has a single form, this is by far the most common scenario in WebForms.  I never said you couldn't have multiple forms, but seeing as he's using a **control**, it *must* have the `runat="server"`, and of those you can only have one.